# Loop over column names in regression

Tags: r

I want to run a whole batch of regressions over every variable in a data frame, and then store the residual deviance value from each regression in a new vector as the loop goes along.

The frame is called "cw". The first few variables are just metadata, so ignore those. I try the following:

```
deviances<-c()
for (x in colnames(cw)[1:8]){deviances[x]<-NA}
for (x in colnames(cw)[8:27]){
  model<-glm(cwonset ~ x, fmaily = binomial, data = cw)
  append(deviances, model$deviance)
}
```

However, it gives the error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = cwonset ~ x, data = cw, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'x')
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Make a reproducible example. That would help us answer this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: i totally agree to @boshek

Answer (score 3):

without data, i had to rely on `mtcars` to help you out, no need of `for` loop also. I assumed `mpg` as the dependent variable

Logic : `sapply` helps me o loop through each colname at a time and then I just regress that. It internally is a `for` loop though

```
sapply(colnames(mtcars[-1]), function(x) {
                                        form <- as.formula(paste0("mpg~", x))
                                        model <- glm(form, data = mtcars)
                                        model$deviance})
#      cyl     disp       hp     drat       wt     qsec       vs       am     gear     carb 
# 308.3342 317.1587 447.6743 603.5667 278.3219 928.6553 629.5193 720.8966 866.2980 784.2711
```